# Facebook Analytics push campaign creating stopped working

Tags: facebook-analytics, facebook-analytics-push

Today getting error each time when I try to create a new in-app push notification campaign. Yesterday it worked fine. Today I am getting error "Sorry, something went wrong" when I try to save

p.s. tried different browsers, machines, clearing cookies, cache etc.

Any suggestions ??

[screenshot if it helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiN6V.png)

Comment: Yes it's not working for me as well

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue. Facebook is working on a fix for the issue and is expected to be fixed within the next few days